# ifstream - Move to next word

Tags: c++, string, ifstream, cpu-word

I am a little bit unclear as to how ifstream functions. I have searched, but can't find a specific answer to this question.

What I am trying to do is stop at a certain word, but then do something with the word after that.

Specifically, my program looks through a file containing words. Each time it sees the string "NEWWORD" it needs to do something with the word following "NEWWORD"

```
string str;
ifstream file;
file.open("wordFile.txt");
while(file >> str){
   //Look through the file
   if(str == "NEWWORD"){
        //Do something with the word following NEWWORD
   }

}     
file.close;
```

How can I tell ifstream to go to the next word?

P.S: Sorry if I did anything wrong as far as guidelines and rules. This is my first time posting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each time you extract from a stream using `>>` it automatically advances to the next item (that is how your `while` loop keeps advancing through the file until it finds "NEWWORD". You can just extract the next item when you see "NEWWORD":

```
string str;
ifstream file;
file.open("wordFile.txt");
while(file >> str){
   //Look through the file
   if(str == "NEWWORD"){
        //Do something with the word following NEWWORD
        if (file >> str) {
             // the word following NEWWORD is now in str
        }
   }

}     
file.close;
```

Comment: Alright. I was thinking it advanced at the end of the loop. Thank you.

Comment: @mattnewport How should I modify the porgram if I have comma separated strings and I want to get the string next of the particular string?

Answer (score 0):

To clarify matt's answer, using `>>` on a istream will find the next character that is not a space, and then read in all characters it finds until it reaches a space character or end of file.